# Cat all files in a directory, with a specific file at the beginning an end...?

Tags: find

Is there a way to `cat` all files in a given directory, but with a particular file at the beginning and end?

For example, say I have: file1.js, file2.js, file3.js, file4.js, file5.js -- Effectively I would like to `cat file2.js file*.js file3.js > /var/www/output.js`

I've tried a few variations of these

```
find ! -name "file2.js" ! -name "file3.js" -type f -exec cat file2.js {} file3.js > /var/www/js/output.js \;
find ! -name "file2.js" ! -name "file3.js" -type f | xargs -I files cat file2.js files file3.js > /var/www/output.js
```

but the best I can get out of it is file2.js added before and file3.js added after all other files (multiple times)

I know I could specify the files in the order I wanted manually, but this is not maintainable (I'm expecting, potentially >100 files).

I have looked through `man cat`, as well as a handful of websites devoted to `xargs`, `find` and `cat` to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the extglob option in bash you can do just that:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ cat file2.js !(file[23].js) file3.js > /var/www/output.js
```

Comment: I just found an answer that appears to work for myself:

    `cat file2.js $(find ! -name "file2.js" ! -name "file3.js" -type f) file3.js > /var/www/output.js`

Thanks for answering!

Comment: I have set up using your method as it looks cleaner. Thanks again for your help.